# TextButton not responding with InputListener on libGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch

I was able to **draw** my buttons, but **nothing happens when I click/"touch" them**, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone please help? Shouldn't the textButtonStyle change to "ToothButton" when it's touched? Am I not supposed to use an InputListener for an Android app?

MainMenuButtons.java

```
public class MainMenuButtons extends Stage {

Stage buttons;
MMButton startButton, optionButton;

public MainMenuButtons(Viewport viewport) {

    startButton = new MMButton(634,550, "Start");
    optionButton = new MMButton(634,450, "Options");

    buttons = new Stage(viewport);

    buttons.addActor(startButton);
    buttons.addActor(optionButton);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}
```

MMButton.java (Main Menu Button)

```
public class MMButton extends Actor{
    TextButton button;
    TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle;
    BitmapFont font;
    Skin skin;
    TextureAtlas buttonAtlas;


    public MMButton(int x, int y, String name) {
        font = new BitmapFont();
        skin = new Skin();

        buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("menuButton.atlas"));
        skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);

        textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.font = font;
        textButtonStyle.up = skin.newDrawable("ToothButtonUp");
        textButtonStyle.down = skin.newDrawable("ToothButton");

        button = new TextButton(name, textButtonStyle);
        button.setBounds(x, y, 246, 90);
        button.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);


        button.addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("down");
                return true;
            }
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button ) {
                super.touchUp( event, x, y, pointer, button );
            }
        });
    }
```

MainMenuScreen.java (I'm sorry for all the code I really just want this problem solved!) :(

OrthoCamera is a class I got online that simplified the use of a camera.

public class MainMenuScreen extends Screen{

```
private OrthoCamera camera;
MainMenuButtons buttons;

@Override
public void create() {
    camera = new OrthoCamera();
    buttons = new MainMenuButtons(new ScreenViewport());
}
@Override
public void update() {
    camera.update();
    buttons.draw();
}
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    buttons.draw();
}
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.resize();
    buttons.getViewport().update(width,height,true);

}
```

Comment: I guess, your `Stage` is not set as `InputProcessor`. You are extending `Stage` and set your `MainMenuButtons`-class as inputprocessor. But inside your `MainMenuButtons` you are creating a new `Stage`, which then contains all `Button`s. This `Stage` is not set as the `InputProcessor`, so it does not get the input events. So the `buttons` should be your `InputProcessor` and you don't need to subclass `Stage`.

Comment: Yes! It seems that all of the answers to this post relate to that same concept. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the MainMenuButtons class. It has two stages. One (buttons) has the button actors added to it, and the other (this) is set as the input processor. That's no good.

There are two solutions.

**Either...**

Replace this line...

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
```

With this...

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(buttons);
```

And don't bother extending stage.

**Or (if you really want to extend stage)...**

Get rid of the buttons variable altogether, and replace these lines...

```
buttons.addActor(startButton);
buttons.addActor(optionButton);
```

With this...

```
addActor(startButton);
addActor(optionButton);
```

Comment: I love you so much. Thank you!!
I stuck with your first method and removed the extensions from both classes. I guess I don't fully understand what extends and implements mean and must research more

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues.

1. You have a stage within a stage. The inner stage has your buttons in it, but it's not set as the input processor. Remove the inner stage and use the outer one directly. Or if you're trying to organize your code here, make your MainMenuButtons class *not* extend Stage (and give it a `getStage()` method so the game class can call `act` and `draw` on it).
2. You never call `act` on your stage, so it won't respond to or act on anything.
3. Your MMButton class contains an inner Button instance that is never added to the Stage, so the inner Button will never receive touch events, even though it has a listener. You could make the MMButton class extend Group instead of Actor, and add the inner Button to it via `addActor()`. But I think you are reinventing the wheel here. You don't need an MMButton class when you can use the existing TextButton class directly--it's already an Actor itself. From what I can see, MMButton is a redundant wrapper.

Sidenote: It is inadvisable to use separate texture atlases and fonts for each button. A texture atlas is meant to be shared by many objects to take advantage of sprite batching.

Comment: The reason that MMButtons is a redundant wrapper is that I tried to create a separate java class that handled all of the menu buttons for the sake of organization. Because MainMenuButtons inherits Stage, doesn't that mean that whenever I call `act` and whatnot, then the child would automatically call the parent's methods?

Thank you so much anyways. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: "Child" is not a Java term. I was using the word child to refer to the reference to a stage that your MainMenuButtons class has. You can call `act` on an instance of MainMenuButtons because an instance of MainMenuButtons is also an instance of Stage. There is no automatic behavior like what you're describing, where the Java compiler would check if a class has any references to objects that inherit from a superclass of this class and calls methods on it. That is super-confusing, and thankfully does not happen!